# Fix table header vertically but not horizontally

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've created a table which is scroll-able both vertically and horizontally. I would like to fix the header so that

- When I scroll the table horizontally, the header moves
- When I scroll the table vertically, the header does not move

How can I do that? Solution with pure CSS are preferred.
Link: https://prova2prova1.altervista.org/GaS/leaderboard.php?ID=12694

Comment: give some fixed height to the table and  use overflow scroll, this will help u. For the horizontal scroll its working fine as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css `position:fixed` property to fix the header at a certain position.

For further info [visit this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp)

Comment: `body {  
margin: 0;  
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
width: 200%;  
overflow-x: auto;  
}`  
I edited the code in the link. Now the page is scroll-able horizontally, but after the header becomes 'sticky' it doesn't move horizontally.